At what point does the Superliminal free trial cut you off?
I’m playing Superliminal on my iPhone (it released a couple days ago), and you can either play the free trial, or buy the full game.
I just finished the trial, fell down the square hole pit, and reached the loading screen where the cube that the loading bar is on turns to the left and continues to the right a bit, before it asked if I wanted to buy the full game.
What percentage of the game does the free trial cut you off at?

The full version of Superliminal has nine levels. The free trial on mobile stops after the first level Induction. Since Superliminal is a puzzle game, the amount of time it takes to complete each level will vary greatly from player to player, but later levels will likely take longer as puzzle difficulty increases.
Source: I previously completed Superliminal on PC and downloaded the mobile demo for this question.
